# jQuery Mobile ajaxEnabled doesn't work?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Running latest release of jQuery Mobile (1.0.1), and do not want to use AJAX for page navigation.

I added the following code which according to jQuery Mobile website should stop the use of AJAX:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

But it still uses AJAX and adds the hash (# ) to URLs.

How can I disable the use of AJAX?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just a guess, but are you binding to `mobileinit` before jQuery Mobile is loaded?

As stated in the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html), you'll want to load the JavaScript files in this order:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```